# How to customize share user interface of Alfresco 7.2 installed using Docker

Tags: docker-compose, customization, alfresco-share

I installed **Alfresco Communiy 7.2 using Docker compose on Ubuntu 20.04**. I want to customize the Share interface, such as changing default logos, share login page, a custom UI theme, etc.
My question is:
How can I do this, which files are affected and how can I modify them?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

First you need to learn Alfresco SDK.
This is used to make customization in alfresco and generate jar/amp which we can deploy so original file will remain untouched and through override technique we can achive.

https://docs.alfresco.com/content-services/6.0/develop/sdk/